# Avoiding infinite loops in __getattribute__

Tags: python, python-3.x

The method `__getattribute__` needs to be written carefully in order to avoid the infinite loop. For example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 100

    def __getattribute__(self, x):
        return self.x

>>> a = A()
>>> a.x    # infinite looop
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 100

    def __getattribute__(self, x):
        return self.__dict__[x]

>>> b = B()
>>> b.x    # infinite looop
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Hence we need to write the method in this way:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 100

    def __getattribute__(self, x):
        # 1. error
        # AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__getattr__'
        # return object.__getattr__(self, x)
        
        # 2. works
        return object.__getattribute__(self, x)
        
        # 3. works too
        # return super().__getattribute__(x)
```

My question is why does `object.__getattribute__` method work? From where does `object` get the `__getattribute__` method? And if `object` does not have any `__getattribute__`, then we are just calling the same method on class `C` but via the super class. Why, then calling the method via super class does not result in an infinite loop?

Comment: Are you sure you need `__getattribute__` and not `__getattr__`?

Comment: Yes I am, because I need to intercept ALL the attribute fetches in my class. But even if I didn't, I would still want to know the full details of why this is so.

Comment: Well, either you have to intercept *all* attribute access or you don't :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I agree. My main confusion is WHY calling the SAME method from `object` does not result in infinite recursion.

Comment: Why do you say that "object does not have any `__getattribute__`"?  `a = object(); dir(a)` and you'll see it listed ...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that your implementation of `__getattribute__` is merely a hook, that if you provide it Python will call it, and otherwise the interpreter will do its normal magic directly.

That is not correct. When python looks up attributes on instances, `__getattribute__` is the main entry for all attribute access, and `object` provides the default implementation. Your implementation is thus *overriding* the original, and if your implementation provides no alternative means of returning attributes it fails. You *cannot* use attribute access in that method, since all attribute access to the instance (`self`) is channelled again through `type(self).__getattribute__(self, attr)`.

The best way around this is by calling the overridden original again. That's where `super(C, self).__getattribute__(attr)` comes in; you are asking the next class in the class-resolution order to take care of the attribute access for you.

Alternatively, you can call the unbound `object.__getattribute__()` method directly. The C implementation of this method is the final stop for attribute access (it has direct access to `__dict__` and is thus not bound to the same limitations).

Note that `super()` returns a proxy object that'll look up whatever method can be found next in the method-resolution ordered base classes. If no such method exists, it'll fail with an attribute error. It will *never* call the original method. Thus `Foo.bar()` looking up `super(Foo, self).bar` will either be a base-class implementation or an attribute error, *never* `Foo.bar` itself.

Answer (score 11):

When you do this:

```
    return object.__getattribute__(self, x)
```

you are calling a specific function -- the one defined in the object class, and not the one defined in A, so there is no recursion.

When you do this:

```
    return self.x
```

you are letting python choose which function to call, and it calls the one from A, and you have an infinite recursion.

Comment: There is NO such function defined on the `object` class. If there were a function defined there, then `object` would also define `__getattr__` (which, as the #1 error shows it does not). So, then why would object define just the `__getattribute__` method?

Comment: @greengit: why wouldn't it? I see `<slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'object' objects>` when I access `object.__getattribute__`.

Comment: So you're saying `object` only defines `__getattribte__` and NOT `__getattr__`? As far as I know, the `object` class's implementation of all these methods are no-op. Correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: @greengit: `object` only implements `__getattribute__`. That method will call `__getattr__` if it is available and the attribute wasn't found elsewhere. It is decidedly *not* a no-op.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Looks like you are correct. A simple `dir(object)` shows that `object` ONLY defines a `__getattribute__`, and NO `__getattr__`. I thouught `object` had no-op implementations for ALL the methods.

Comment: @greengit: Nope, `object.__getattribute__` is the main access point for object attribute access. When you define that on a subclass, you are overriding it and to get the *normal* behaviour again you need to call the overridden implementation.

Comment: "I thought object had no-op implementations"? Why in the world...? How would things even work if the root object's implementations of special methods were no-ops? What would you be overriding when you wrote your own? How would those overrides access the base functionality if the base methods didn't do anything? It doesn't even make sense.

Answer (score 5):

Write it like this (**C** inherits from **object**):

```
class C(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.x = 100

   def __getattribute__(self, x):
       return object.__getattribute__(self, x)
```

Now you see why object.__getattribute__(self, x) works - you are calling parent object.