# Why there is no infinite loop while overriding getattr method in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, getattr, getattribute

I am trying to override getattr method and as per my understanding
there should be infinite loop in the following code snippet as by default
**object.__getattribute__(self,attr)** is invoked which will invoke overrided getattr method as attribute 'notpresent' is not present in namespaces and this process will be keep on repeating. Can anybody help me in figuring out that why this behavior is not observed here.

Moreover I am unable to figure out that why AttributeError is not raised when implicit call to getattribute is done while accessing attribute using dot notation while it is being raised second time when we are trying to invoke getattribute explicitly within method

```
class Test(object):

    #Act as a fallback and is invoked when getattribute is unable to find attribute

    def __getattr__(self,attr):

        print "getattr is called"
        return object.__getattribute__(self,attr) #AttributeError is raised

t=Test([1,2,3,4])

b = t.notpresent
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: avoiding infinite loops in \_\_getattribute\_\_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538324/python-avoiding-infinite-loops-in-getattribute)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `object.__getattribute__` within `Test.__getattr__`.

There is no loop involved here.

Moreover, as per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__), `__getattribute__` does not implicitly call `__getattr__`.

#### Update after your edit

[Here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7862ded73723e4573ed5d13488c07b41ac31a07e/Objects/typeobject.c#L6000-L6076) is the C-implementation of the `__getattribute__` call. Especially the `slot_tp_getattr_hook` part.

In your case, the attribute lookup failure lead to the execution of line 6072 that calls your custom `__getattr__` function.

From there on, the `AttributeError` has been cleared. But your call to `object.__getattribute__` will set it back and line 6074 or 6075 won't handle it.

The `object.__getattribute__` call is implemented [like so](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/829b49cbd2e4b1d573470da79ca844b730120f3d/Objects/object.c#L1028-L1120) and thus (re)raise `AttributeError` (line 1107).

Comment: As per docs overrided getattr should be called if AttributeError is raised

Comment: `AttributeError` has already been handled, because `Test.__getattr__` is being called. Thus explicitly calling `object.__getattribute__` is exactly the same as calling it from `Test.__getattribute__` to avoid infinite loops.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `__getattribute__` normally only looks up the attribute in the `__dict__` of the object and similar places - it does not implicitely call `__getattr__` to retrieve the attribute.

Note that if `__getattribute__` would call `__getattr__` the `__getattr__` method might be called twice if `__getattribute__` failed to find the attribute (since lookup is supposed to call `__getattr__` when `__getattribute__` fails).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Perhaps, but just commenting "Sorry but plain wrong" does not help. Could you explain in what way my answer is wrong?

Comment: `__getattribute__` does not "normally only looks up the attribute in the `__dict__` of the object." - it handles the whole attribute lookup, including descriptors (computed attributes), looking up the instance's dicts OR slots, and looking up the class and parents classes.