# How does object.__getattribute__ avoid a RuntimeError?

Tags: python, recursion, magic-methods

In the rare cases that an object's `__getattribute__` method must be overridden, a common mistake is to try and return the attribute in question like so:

```
class WrongWay:
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        # Custom functionality goes here
        return self.__dict__[name]
```

This code always yields a `RuntimeError` due to a recursive loop, since `self.__dict__` is in itself an attribute reference that calls upon the same `__getattribute__` method.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/371833/2977638), the correct solution to this problem is to replace last line with:

```
...
        return super().__getattribute__(self, name) # Defer responsibility to the superclass
```

This solution works when run through the Python 3 interpreter, but it also seems to violate `__getattribute__`'s promised functionality. Even if the superclass chain is traversed up to `object`, at the end of the line somebody will eventually have to return `self.`*something*, and by definition that attribute reference must first get through the child's `__getattribute__` method.

How does Python get around this recursion issue? In `object.__getattribute__`, how is anything returned without looping into another request?

Comment: I think you meant `super().__getattribute__(name)`, not `super().__getattribute__(self, name)`

Comment: Anyway, I won't hammer your question because it's an interesting and well written one, but here's a possible duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/q/13538324/674039

Comment: @wim Indeed, my question is a duplicate! My apologies; I had tried hard to ensure this question wouldn't add clutter to the site. I will look up how to mark the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> at the end of the line somebody will eventually have to return `self.`*something*, and by definition that attribute reference must first get through the child's `__getattribute__()` method.

That's not correct. `object.__getattribute__` is not defined as returning `self.anything`, and it does not respect descendant class implementations of `__getattribute__`. `object.__getattribute__` is the default attribute access implementation, and it always performs its job through the default attribute access mechanism.

Similarly, `object.__eq__` is not defined as returning `self == other_thing`, and it does not respect descendant class implementations of `__eq__`. `object.__str__` is not defined as returning `str(self)`, and it does not respect descendant class implementations of `__str__`. `object`'s methods are the default implementations of those methods, and they always do the default thing.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me! So, to clarify, the "default attribute access mechanism" you mention is only elucidated in Python's C implementation? I was under the false impression that any "magic method" would still be defined under Python's syntax and constraints, therefore greatly complicating `__getattribute__`'s strategy.

Comment: @RNanoware: If you want to take a look, it's [`PyObject_GenericGetAttr`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/object.c#l1116) in `Objects/object.c`.